# Pandas conditional computation based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Considering this dataframe:

```
data = {'A':[1.5, 2, 3, 4], 'B':[3, 5, 8, 7], 'C':['abc', 'def', 'zyw', 'lol'], 'D':['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd like to compute the sum of the `A` column based on condition `x <= 2.5 & D == 'AAA'` and append the result to the same dataframe, but without the rows that match the condition. The strings should be concatenated.

So, I came up with this:

```
logic = (df['A'] <= 2.5) & (df['D'] == 'AAA')
df_1 = df[logic].sum()
df_2 = df[~logic]
df_2.append(df_1, ignore_index=True)
```

returning

```
    A   B   C       D
0   3.0 8   zyw    BBB
1   4.0 7   lol    CCC
2   3.5 8   abcdef AAAAAA
```

Is there any other, more pythonic (oneliner maybe) solution?

Comment: "more pythonic (oneliner maybe) " just in general, do not consider one-liners synonymous with pythonic

Comment: ... but of course, you could do: `df[~logic].append(df[logic].sum(), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Err, didn't see the requirement for dropping those other rows :-(

Comment: What about by using the ´apply´ or ´agg´ function?

Comment: @PythonNoob Nope, juan's solution is the best.